how to configure server aliases using samba-tool
My home domain is named  cn.lan. I have a server called wsubu.cn.lan which is recognized within my local active directory domain which uses samba. There is this tool:
samba-tool
that can be used to add users, etc. I wonder if there is a way to create an alias for my wsubu.cn.lan so I can use:  playground.cn.lan to replace   wsubu.cn.lan:8000
The 8000 is just any value.

Based on the information you've provided, it sounds as if you want to create a CNAME Record, which should allow you to point to another domain, etc.
samba-tool dns add <Server_Name> <Zone_Name> <Alias_Name> CNAME <Target_Domain>


samba-tool dns add: Initiates the command to add a new DNS record.
Server_Name: The hostname of your Samba domain controller.
Zone_Name: The DNS zone where you want to add the CNAME record
Alias_Name: The name you want to use as the alias
CNAME: Specifies that you are adding a CNAME (canonical name) record
Target_Domain: The full domain name you want the alias to point to

Assuming "wsubu" Server is a Samba Domain Controller, you may want to try the following.
samba-tool dns wsubu.cn.lan cn.lan "wsubu" CNAME playground.cn.lan

If you run into Issues, you may want to read through the following Samba Article, which covers how to create AD ObjectGUID CNAME Records, etc.
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Verifying_and_Creating_a_DC_DNS_Record
In fact, the entire site is filled with useful Samba related information, along with the following Wiki Page.
https://wiki.indie-it.com/wiki/Samba
